# How to compare cell value with textbox value in another cell in same row of html table

Tags: php, jquery, onclick, onblur

I've below table which displays values of product name and available stock retrieved from database. I want to insert quantity value and validate it with available stock value in that cell. The code is:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="edit_td">
      <span id="first_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text">
        <?php echo $name; ?>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td class="edit_td">
      <span id="last_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text">
        <?php if($stock==0){echo 0;}else{echo $stock;} ?>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td class="edit_td1" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
      <form id="html5Form" class="form-horizontal" name="form_nm"
            data-fv-framework="bootstrap"
            data-fv-icon-valid="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"
            data-fv-icon-invalid="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
            data-fv-icon-validating="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-lg-3 inputContainer">
            <input class="form-control"
                   id="quanti_<?php echo $id; ?>"
                   name="number"
                   value=""
                   type="text"
                   min="0"
                   max="<?php
                          if($stock==0) {
                            echo 0;
                          } else {
                            echo $stock;
                          } ?>"
                   data-fv-integer-message="Please Enter valid quantity" />

<?php $_SESSION["listofIds"] .= ",".$id; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I tried this Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $(".edit_td1").click(function()
   {
       var ID=$(this).attr('id');
       //alert(ID);
       $('#quanti_'+ID).blur(function(){
       //var ID=$(this).attr('id');
       var qt=$('#quanti_'+ID).val();
       var stk=$('#last_'+ID).html();
       alert(qt);
       alert(stk);

       if (qt>stk)
       {
            alert("Quantity > than stock");
            return false;
       }
       else
          return true;
  });
 });
});
```

And I don't want to submit by user till valid stock and quantity values.

Comment: So what you are getting in `alert` of both the values? and why are you writing `blur` event inside `click`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao- alert(qt) it gives value entered in the textbox  alert(stk) gives avalable stock value from that row .I want valid it after blur of quantity textbox.

Comment: Why are you binding it to `id`? instead you can bind to a common `class` and get the elements using `$(this)` right?